# Pass Context and use SQL in service

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to write some SQL to a database, however when executing it I get a nullpointer error. I think I do something wrong with passing the Context from `WhatsApi.java` to `MessageService.java`. (See the `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`)

This part from `MessageService.java`

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("msgstore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages(`from` TEXT, `to` TEXT, message TEXT, id TEXT, t TEXT);");
```

This in `WhatsApi.java`

```
MessageService msg = new MessageService();
            msg.saveMessage(mContext, "mynumber", to, message, id, time());
```

I suggest you guys to see this link too:

https://github.com/gi097/WhatsApi-Android/commit/3875d97458095f792c73f275648629aaaf726751

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for the maybe unclear look, but I hope you guys understand.

Comment: you can't instanciate a service yourself...

Comment: @njzk2 so what should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Well I use this in one of my Projects

        `DatabaseHandler dbHandler=null;//Database handler class//global var
        SQLiteDatabase contactDatabase=null;// globalvar
        .
        .
       //some function{
        if(dbHandler==null)
            dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);//service context
        if(contactDatabase==null)
            contactDatabase=dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        ArrayList<information>list= new ArrayList<information>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +  DatabaseHandler.TABLE_CONTACTS;
        Cursor cursor = contactDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You should never instantiate an `Activity` or `Service` yourself with the `new` keyword. It is Android's responsibility to start these components because Android needs to also do some additional setup, including provide a base `Context` for these components. That is why you get a `NullPointerException` in your service class. You have to actually use `startService()` to make the service run properly.

In my opinion, since `WhatsApi` already has a Context, I don't see any reason you need to bother having the service save the data. Just open the database and save the data in `WhatsApi`.

By the way, since you're using SQLite, you really should be using `SQLiteOpenHelper` instead of calling methods like `openOrCreateDatabase()` directly. See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) for more information.

Comment: Very clean and helpful! Thanks, will try them.